# Properties of Binary Functions

Tags: code-golf, math, function

Many important topics in abstract algebra involve a binary function acting on a set. A number of properties of such functions have been defined in the investigation of such topics.

Your challenge will be to determine whether a given binary function on a given domain possesses five of these properties.

### Properties

**[Closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics))**

A binary function is closed if every possible output is in the domain.

**[Associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)**

A binary function is associative if the order in which the function is applied to a series of inputs doesn't affect the result. That is, `$` is associative if `(a $ b) $ c` always equals `a $ (b $ c)`. Note that since the value `(a $ b)` is used as an input, associative functions must be closed.

**[Commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)**

A binary function is commutative if swapping the order of the inputs doesn't change the result. In other words, if `a $ b` always equals `b $ a`.

**[Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element)**

A binary function has an identity element if there exists some element `e` in the domain such that `a $ e = a = e $ a` for all `a` in the domain.

**[Idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)**

A binary function is idempotent if applying it to two identical inputs gives that number as the output. In other words, if `a $ a = a` for all `a` in the domain.

### Input

You will be given a function in the form of a matrix, and the domain of the function will be the numbers `0 ... n-1`, where `n` is the side length of the matrix.

The value `(a $ b)` is encoded in the matrix as the `a`th row's `b`th element. If the input matrix is `Q`, then `a $ b` = `Q[a][b]`

For example, the exponentiation function (`**` in Python) on the domain `[0, 1, 2]` is encoded as:

```
[[1, 0, 0]
 [1, 1, 1]
 [1, 2, 4]]
```

The left and right domains are the same, so the matrix will always be square.

You may use any convenient matrix format as input, such as a list of lists, a single list in row- or column- major order, your language's native matrix object, etc. However, you may not take a function directly as input.

For simplicity, the matrix entries will all be integers. You may assume that they fit in your language's native integer type.

### Output

You may indicate which of the above properties hold in any format you choose, including a list of booleans, a string with a different character for each property, etc. However, there must be a distinct, unique output for each of the 24 possible subsets of the properties. This output must be easily human-readable.

### Examples

The maximum function on domain n=4:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3]
 [1, 1, 2, 3]
 [2, 2, 2, 3]
 [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

This function has the properties of closure, associativity, commutativity, identity and idempotence.

The exponentiation function on domain n=3:

```
[[1, 0, 0]
 [1, 1, 1]
 [1, 2, 4]]
```

This function has none of the above properties.

The addition function on domain n=3:

```
[[0, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [2, 3, 4]]
```

This function has the properties of commutativity and identity.

The K combinator on domain n=3:

```
[[0, 0, 0]
 [1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2, 2]]
```

This function has the properties of closure, associativity and idempotence.

The absolute difference function on domain n=3:

```
[[0, 1, 2]
 [1, 0, 1]
 [2, 1, 0]]
```

This function has the properties of closure, commutativity and identity.

The average function, rounding towards even, on domain n=3:

```
[[0, 0, 1]
 [0, 1, 2]
 [1, 2, 2]]
```

This function has the properties of closure, commutativity, identity and idempotence.

The equality function on domain n=3:

```
[[1, 0, 0]
 [0, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 1]]
```

This function has the properties of closure and commutativity.

### Challenge

This is code golf. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. Least bytes wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 51 bytes

```
[qKUQ@VQKCIQ}]Km{@RdCBQKJ!-sQK&JqF.bsm@L@QdYN.p,sQK
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=[qKUQ%40VQKCIQ%7D]Km%7B%40RdCBQKJ!-sQK%26JqF.bsm%40L%40QdYN.p%2CsQK&input=[[0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3]]&test_suite_input=[[0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3]]%0A[[1%2C+0%2C+0]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+1]%2C+[1%2C+2%2C+4]]%0A[[0%2C+1%2C+2]%2C+[1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[2%2C+3%2C+4]]%0A[[0%2C+0%2C+0]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+1]%2C+[2%2C+2%2C+2]]%0A[[0%2C+1%2C+2]%2C+[1%2C+0%2C+1]%2C+[2%2C+1%2C+0]]%0A[[0%2C+0%2C+1]%2C+[0%2C+1%2C+2]%2C+[1%2C+2%2C+2]]%0A[[1%2C+0%2C+0]%2C+[0%2C+1%2C+0]%2C+[0%2C+0%2C+1]]&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=[qKUQ%40VQKCIQ%7D]Km%7B%40RdCBQKJ!-sQK%26JqF.bsm%40L%40QdYN.p%2CsQK&input=[[0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3]]&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[[0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3]]%0A[[1%2C+0%2C+0]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+1]%2C+[1%2C+2%2C+4]]%0A[[0%2C+1%2C+2]%2C+[1%2C+2%2C+3]%2C+[2%2C+3%2C+4]]%0A[[0%2C+0%2C+0]%2C+[1%2C+1%2C+1]%2C+[2%2C+2%2C+2]]%0A[[0%2C+1%2C+2]%2C+[1%2C+0%2C+1]%2C+[2%2C+1%2C+0]]%0A[[0%2C+0%2C+1]%2C+[0%2C+1%2C+2]%2C+[1%2C+2%2C+2]]%0A[[1%2C+0%2C+0]%2C+[0%2C+1%2C+0]%2C+[0%2C+0%2C+1]]&debug=0)

This prints a list of 5 boolean values. They indicate the properties in the order:

```
[Idempotence, Commutativity, Identity, Closure, Associativity]
```

Here is a better output format: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?test_suite=0&input=%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%203%2C%203%2C%203%5D%5D&code=%2B%22Idempotence%3A%20%20%20%22qKUQ.e%40bkQ%0A%2B%22Commutativity%3A%20%22CIQ%0A%2B%22Identity%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7D%5DKm%7B%40RdCBQK%0A%2B%22Closure%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22J%21-sQK%0A%2B%22Associativity%3A%20%22%26JqF.bsm%40LdY%40LQN.p%2CsQK&test_suite_input=%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%203%2C%203%2C%203%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%204%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%203%2C%204%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%2C%202%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%200%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%201%2C%200%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%202%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%5D%5D) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?test_suite=1&input=%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%203%2C%203%2C%203%5D%5D&code=%2B%22Idempotence%3A%20%20%20%22qKUQ.e%40bkQ%0A%2B%22Commutativity%3A%20%22CIQ%0A%2B%22Identity%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%7D%5DKm%7B%40RdCBQK%0A%2B%22Closure%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22J%21-sQK%0A%2B%22Associativity%3A%20%22%26JqF.bsm%40LdY%40LQN.p%2CsQK&test_suite_input=%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C%203%2C%203%2C%203%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%204%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%203%2C%204%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%202%2C%202%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%200%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%201%2C%200%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%202%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%201%2C%200%5D%2C%20%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%5D%5D)

#### Explanation:

**Idempotence:**

```
qKUQ@VQK
   Q       Q = input matrix
  UQ       [0, 1, ..., len(matrix)-1]
 K         assign to K
    @VQK   vectorized lookup of Q and K //gets the diagonal elements
qK         check, if this is equal to K
```

**Commutativity:**

```
CIQ   check if transpose(Q) is equal to Q
```

**Identity:**

```
}]Km{@RdCBQK
   m       K   map each d in K to:
        CBQ       the list [Q, transpose(Q)]
     @Rd          take the d-th element of each ^
    {             remove duplicates
}]K            check if [K] is in ^
```

**Closure:**

```
J!-sQK
   sQ    sum(Q) //all elements of Q
  -  K   remove the elements, that also appear in K
 !       ckeck, if the results in an empty list
J        store the result in J
```

**Associativity:**

```
&JqF.bsm@L@QdYN.p,sQK
               .p,sQK  all permutations of [sum(Q), K] //all 2 ;-)
    .b                 map each pair (N,Y) of ^ to:
       m      N           map each d of N to:
          @Qd                the row Q[d]
        @L   Y               map each element of Y to the corr. element in ^
      s                   unfold this 2-d list
  qF                   check if they result in identically lists
&J                     and J
```

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>178</s> 171 bytes

```
import Data.List
f x=[c,c&&and[(m%n)%o==m%(n%o)|m<-b,n<-b,o<-b],x==t,all(elem b)[x,t],b==[i%i|i<-b]]where c=all(l>)(id=<<x);b=[0..l-1];a%b=x!!a!!b;l=length x;t=transpose x
```

Returns a list with five booleans, which are in order closure, associativity, commutativity, identity and idempotence.

Usage example: `f [[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1]]` -> `[True,False,True,False,False]`.

How it works:

```
f x=[
  c,                         -- closure (see below)
  c&&and[(m%n)%o==m%(n%o)|   -- assoc: make sure it's closed, then check the
          m<-b,n<-b,o<-b],   --        assoc rule for all possible combinations
  x==t,                      -- comm: x must equal it's transposition
  all(elem b)[x,t],          -- identity: b must be a row and a column
  b==[i%i|i<-b]              -- idemp: element at (i,i) must equal i
  ]
  where                      -- some helper functions
  c=all(l>)(id=<<x);         -- closure: all elements of the input must be < l 
  b=[0..l-1];                -- a list with the numbers from 0 to l-1
  a%b=x!!a!!b;               -- % is an access function for index (a,b)
  l=length x;                -- l is the number of rows of the input matrix
  t=transpose x
```

Edit @xnor found some bytes to save. Thanks!

Comment: How about `c=all(l>)`?

Comment: Also, `[i%i|i<-b]==b`.

Comment: Very readable for code-golf - nice!

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 95 bytes

```
q~:Ae_A,:Bf<:*'**B3m*{_{A==}*\W%{Az==}*=}%:*'A*A_z='C*B{aB*ee_Wf%+{A==}f*B,2*='1*}%Ae_B)%B,='I*
```

Prints a subsequence of `*AC1I`. `*` is the symbol for **closure**, `A` is for **associative**, `C` is for **commutative**, `1` is for **identity** and `I` is for **idempotent**.

---

The input array is read `q~` and stored in A (`:A`).

#### Closure

```
Ae_A,:Bf<:*'**
```

If all (`:*`) elements in the matrix (`Ae_`) are smaller `f<` than B=size(A) (`A,:B`), print a `*` (`'**`).

#### Associativity

```
B3m*{_{A==}*\W%{Az==}*=}%:*'A*
```

Generate all triples in the domain (`B3m*`). We print `A` if they all satisfy a condition (`{...}%:*'A*`).

The condition is that, for some triple `[i j k]`, left-folding that list with **A** (`_{A==}*`) and left-folding its reverse `[k j i]` (`\W%`) with **A<sup>op</sup>** (`{Az==}*`), the flipped version of `A`, are equal (`=`).

#### Commutativity

**A** must equal its transpose: `A_z=`. If so, we print `C` (`'C=`).

#### Identity

```
B{                         }%   For each element X in the domain (0..N-1):
  aB*                           Make N copies.
     ee                         [[0 X] [1 X] ...]
       _Wf%+                    [[0 X] [1 X] ... [X 0] [X 1] ...]
            {A==}f*             [A(0, X) A(1, X) ... A(X, 0) A(X, 1)]
                   B,2*=        This list should equal the domain list repeated twice.
                        '1*     If so, X is an identity: print a 1.
```

The identity is necessarily unique, so we can only print one `1`.

#### Idempotent

```
Ae_B)%B,='I*
```

Check if the diagonal equals `B,`. If so, print an `I`.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 226

```
a=input('');n=size(a,1);v=1:n;c=all(0<=a(:)&a(:)<n);A=c;for i=v;for j=v(1:n*c);for k=v(1:n*c);A=A&a(a(i,j)+1,k)==a(i,a(j,k)+1);end;end;b(i)=all(a(i,:)==v-1 & a(:,i)'==v-1);end;disp([c,A,~norm(a-a'),any(b),all(diag(a)'==v-1)])
```

An important thing to notice is that non-closed implies non-associative. Many of those properties can easily be checked using some properties of the matrix:

- **Closure**: All all matrix entries in the given range?
- **Associativity**: As always the most difficult one to check
- **Commutativity**: Is the matrix symmetric?
- **Identity**: Is there an index k such that the k-th row and k-th column are exactly the list of the indices?
- **Idempotence**: Does the diagonal correspond to the list of indices?

Input via standar Matlab notation: `[a,b;c,d]` or `[[a,b];[c,d]]` or `[a b;c d]` e.t.c.

Output is a vector of ones a zeros, 1 = true, 0 = false, for each of the properties in the given order.

Full code:

```
a=input('');
n=size(a,1);
v=1:n;
c=all(0<=a(:)&a(:)<n);               %check for closedness
A=c;
for i=v;
   for j=v(1:n*c); 
      for k=v(1:n*c);
          A=A&a(a(i,j)+1,k)==a(i,a(j,k)+1);   %check for associativity (only if closed)
      end;
   end;
   b(i)=all(a(i,:)==v-1 & a(:,i)'==v-1);      %check for commutativity
end
%closure, assoc, commut, identity, idempotence
disp([c,A,~norm(a-a'),any(b),all(diag(a)'==v-1)]);
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) 165

An anonymous function returning an array with five 0/1 values, which are in order Closure, Associativity, Commutativity, Identity and Idempotence.

```js
q=>q.map((p,i)=>(p.map((v,j)=>(w=q[j][i],v-w?h=C=0:v-j?h=0:0,q[v]?A&=!q[v].some((v,k)=>v-q[i][q[j][k]]):A=K=0),h=1,p[i]-i?P=0:0),h?I=1:0),A=P=K=C=1,I=0)&&[K,A,C,I,P]
```

**Less golfed**

```js
f=q=>(
  // A associativity, P idempotence, K closure, C commuativity
  // assumed true until proved false
  A=P=K=C=1, 
  I=0, // Identity assumed false until an identity element is found
  q.map((p,i)=> (
      h=1, // assume current i is identity until proved false
      p[i]-i? P=0 :0, // not idempotent if q[i][i]!=i for any i
      p.map((v,j)=> (
          w=q[j][i], // and v is q[i][j]
          v-w // check if q[j][i] != q[i][j]
          ? h=C=0 // if so, not commutative and i is not identity element too
          : v-j // else, check again for identity
            ? h=0 // i is not identity element if v!=j or w!=j
            : 0,
          q[v] // check if q[i][j] in domain
            ? A&=!q[v].some((v,k)=>v-q[i][q[j][k]]) // loop for associativity check
            : A=K=0 // q[i][j] out of domain, not close and not associative
        )
      ),
      h ? I=1 : 0 // if i is the identity element the identity = true
    )
  ),
  [K,A,C,I,P] // return all as an array
)
```

**Test**

```js
f=q=>
  q.map((p,i)=>(
    p.map((v,j)=>(
      w=q[j][i],
      v-w?h=C=0:v-j?h=0:0,
      q[v]?A&=!q[v].some((v,k)=>v-q[i][q[j][k]]):A=K=0
    ),h=1,p[i]-i?P=0:0),
    h?I=1:0
  ),A=P=K=C=1,I=0)
  &&[K,A,C,I,P]

// test

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n';

T=[
 [
  [[0, 1, 2, 3],
   [1, 1, 2, 3],
   [2, 2, 2, 3],
   [3, 3, 3, 3]]
 ,[1,1,1,1,1]] // has the properties of closure, associativity, commutativity, identity and idempotence.
,[ // exponentiation function on domain n=3:
  [[1, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [1, 2, 4]]
 ,[0,0,0,0,0]] // has none of the above properties.
,[ // addition function on domain n=3:
  [[0, 1, 2],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4]] 
 ,[0,0,1,1,0]] // has the properties of commutativity and identity.
,[ // K combinator on domain n=3:
  [[0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2]]
 ,[1,1,0,0,1]] // has the properties of closure, associativity and idempotence.
,[ // absolute difference function on domain n=3:
  [[0, 1, 2],
   [1, 0, 1],
   [2, 1, 0]]
 ,[1,0,1,1,0]] // has the properties of closure, commutativity and identity.
,[ // average function, rounding towards even, on domain n=3:
  [[0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [1, 2, 2]]
 ,[1,0,1,1,1]] // has the properties of closure, commutativity, identity and idempotence.
,[ // equality function on domain n=3:
  [[1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]]
 ,[1,0,1,0,0]] // has the properties of closure, commutativity,
]  

T.forEach(t=>{
  F=t[0],X=t[1]+'',R=f(F)+'',console.log(F.join`\n`+'\n'+R+' (expected '+X+') '+(X==R?'OK\n':'Fail\n'))
  })
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```